# Accessing global variables in pthreads in different c-files

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, global-variables, posix

I have a main.c with a global variable called `int countboards`. In the main() I start a  pthread, that listens to ONE TCP-Connection and runs that through (progserver.c). Means, this thread will never return. In the main() I enter the function `rmmain(...)` which is in the rm.c (RM=Ressource Manager). In rm.c I read `countboards`, in the progserver.c in the pthread I write to this variable (both are made accessible by `extern int countboards`).

So the problem is, when I write to `countboards` in the pthread and I want to access this variable after it's been written to in the rm.c, it still has the old value (in this case 0 instead of for example 10). Why?

main.c:

```
int countboards;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  countboards = 0;
  pthread_t thread;
  pthread_create(&thread, NULL, startProgramserver, NULL);

  rmmain();

  return 0;
}
```

rm.c:

```
extern int countboards;

int rmmain(vhbuser* vhbuserlist, int countvhbuser,
       userio* useriolist, int countios, int usertorm, int rmtosslserver, int sslservertorm) {
  while(1) {
    int n;
    n=read(usertorm,buf,bufc); // blocks until command comes from the user
    ...
    board* b = findAFreeBoard(boardlist, countboards, usagelist); // here countboards should be >0, but it isn't
    ...
  }
}
```

programserver.c:

```
extern int countboards;
void* startProgramserver(void*) {
  ...
  sock = tcp_listen();
  ...
  http_serve(ssl,s, sslpipes);
}

static int http_serve(SSL *ssl, int s, void* sslpipes) {
  ...
  countboards = countboards + countboardscommands;
  ...
  // here countboards has the new value
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're seeing a cached copy in each thread. I would suggest declaring it `volatile int countboards` except that's really not a good way to go about things.

Globals are kinda evil. You'd be better served by passing a pointer to each thread and synchronizing with a mutex.

**Edit:** To expand on this since I was in a hurry last night ...

http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2007/11/30/volatile-almost-useless-for-multi-threaded-programming/

As [KasigiYabu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/467961/kasigiyabu) mentions in the comments below, creating a "context" structure that contains all the information you want to share between the threads and passing that in to `pthread_create` as the last arg is a sound approach and is what I do as well in most cases.

Comment: Yes it should be declared `volatile`, but it should also be protected by a mutex to ensure atomicity.

Comment: If it's protected by a mutex for both reads and writes, volatile is not needed (and only hurts performance)

Comment: passing like this? `pthread_create(&thread, NULL, startProgramserver, &countboards);` and in the thread going from void* back to int? What when I have 2 variables? How do I pass a `int` and a `board` variable (`board` is a self-made struct)?

Comment: You can create a Context struct that contains all the variables that thread needs and pass a pointer to that struct. Anyway, using volatile may not be enough - mutexes are necessary for me. It may be that your compiler optimizes something for you (e.g. when you use your global variable as a loop condition) and then you will get surprising and very difficult to detect bugs...

Comment: @KasigiYabu - exactly. That's usually my standard approach as well.